# SAS: How to create variables from the values given in a specific column of a table?

Tags: sas

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWSze.png]

I'm using SAS and have come across a problem. I have a dataset with some variables / columns, one of which has values of only the following: `blue`, `red`, and `gray`. How can I convert these values into respective variables and assign the `count` as values, as shown in the second table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `proc transpose`

```
proc transpose data=YourData out=NewData;
    by Color;
    id Name; /* This column in your data needs a name and to be filled down */
    var Count;
run;
```